# How can I ensure this vue application doesn't exceed the recommended 244kb in production?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There is a vue file here that imports a json file that has about 9000 records in it.
How do I ensure that the json file is not compiled with the component?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic import. Like this:

```
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: "my_json" */
    './src/my.json'
).then(({default: myJson}) => {
    // do whatever you like here~
    console.log(myJson);
});
```

doc:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

If the json file is too big, you will still get the size exceeding warning.
But the json file would load async, so it would not cause any performance problem.

if you really don't want to see the warning, try this:

Use  [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)，it can copy your json file to `dist` folder, which means you can fire a `XHR get` request to load the json file, like this `axios.get('/my.json')`.
By doing this, you can get the **FULL** control about when to load the file.

Comment: Thanks @Old_dream, This would work but it doesn't solve my problem. like you mentioned it would still compile with the production build anyway, it would just get it asynchronously

Comment: The async loading would not block the script from running.So it solve the problem of performance.@AfolayanFavour

Comment: Yeah. [@Old_dream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7311832/old-dream), I did try using the copy-webpack-plugin, since it copies the file into the `dist` folder at build time, the console still complains about the size of the file which I know I cannot do anything about at this time.
But yeah, it doesn't include it in the build anyways. So I will take this.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to put the JSON file you want to access in the `public` folder ([Webpack won't process anything in this folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling)). Then use AJAX to call the file at run time.

**This will avoid expanding your app bundle, but Vue may still show that you're including a large resource.** This approach would also allow you to split the data into smaller chunks and load them as needed in your app.

Here's an example, assuming the data file is located at `/public/data/mydata.json`. Also, I suggest using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make the AJAX stuff easier.

```js
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'Vue Component',
  created() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      axios.get('/data/mydata.json').then(response => {
        // do something with response.data
      })
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh nice. I implemented this already but was hoping there would be something else to do to make it become completely small and below the 244kb recommended. Thanks [@Bryce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6268914/bryce-howitson)